# Include filepath for css file in R Markdown YAML

Tags: r, r-markdown, xaringan

I need to link my R Markdown to a css file. If the css file is in the same directory as the .Rmd file, it works without problems. If the css is in a different directory, it does not work.

**How do I include a file path in the css field of my YAML?**

This does *not* work

```
---
title: "MY TITLE"
author: "MY NAME"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    css: path/to/xaringan_themer.css
    nature:
      highlightStyle: tomorrow-night-bright
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
      titleSlideClass: ["center","top"]
---
```

Comment: Not sure if this is recommended. In Rmarkdown, when your document renders, it looks immediately in the root directory for the necessary files, This is just how Rmarkdown works by default. Suggesting you keep the CSS in the same directory as the .Rmd file.

Comment: After tests, this works when the path you provide belongs to the **subdirectories** of the root folder where the `.Rmd` is located

Comment: Perhaps this [discussion](https://github.com/jdblischak/workflowr/issues/95#issuecomment-359953292) helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I explore this topic which is a "hot" one for years.
The last news is a new issue which pointing out all previous one and offers a solution https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1859. Author stating that his branches https://github.com/jonathan-g/rmarkdown/tree/jg-devel and https://github.com/jonathan-g/rmarkdown/tree/minimal-tree-fix (this last one is pruning my changes down to a minimal patch to keep the PR small) offers a solution for this problem. The PR is still not exists at this point, with the last update a few months ago.

Other solution (which i like) might be usage of symlinks, presented here: https://github.com/jdblischak/workflowr/issues/95#issuecomment-360138007
What is important, symlinks are supported by git. Example at https://github.com/stephenslab/wflow-divvy/tree/dev under organized dir.